# Vue3, which repository to use, vue3, or vue-next

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vuejs-transition

So,

This is probably a stupid question, but I just can't find an answer anywhere.
From the VueJS docs, in the migration steps they say I should change my package.json to use:

```
vue: "^3.1.0"
```

But in the introduction, they say I should use:

```
vue-next: "^3.1.0"
```

what is the difference?
do I interpret it correctly as that vue is just the transition repository?

If I move from 2 > 3, do I have to use the vue one? or can I just start using vue-next immediately?(with changes ofcourse).

probably stupid, but I am a bit confused by the docs now.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vue-next` must be a typo (or outdated info) in the docs because [`vue-next`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-next) is an unmaintained pre-alpha package, and `vue` is stable for 3.x versions. However, `"vue-next"` doesn't appear in the [Vue 3 Introduction](https://github.com/vuejs/docs/blob/77c2c01/src/guide/introduction.md), but [`"vue@next"` is seen under *Installation*](https://github.com/vuejs/docs/blob/master/src/guide/installation.md) (where [`next` is just an alias for 3.x](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue?activeTab=versions)).

Just install `vue` like this:

```sh
npm i -S vue@^3.x

# or
npm i -S vue@next
```